# Magento tiered pricing change format

Tags: php, magento

At the moment, my webstore uses several different customer groups to provide discounts, such as trade discounts. The functionality works fine, but i want to change the way the prices are displayed on the front end. Right now, the prices show like this:

```
£700.00

Buy 1 for £450.00 each and save 36%
```

For instance. So the customer is logged in, they can see the Retail price and then their price is the £450. I wish for it to say

```
List Price: £700.00
Your Price: £450.00 (save 36%).
```

Is this possible?

The other issue is that when a customer is not logged in, i just want them to see the list price, and not the discounts etc.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. You have to play with the file **price.phtml** and/or **view.phtml**.
To get original price, use getPrice() method on your product object. To get discounted (final) price, use getFInalPrice()

Product object is usually $_product, so

```
$_product->getPrice();
$_product->getFinalPrice();
```

Now you may display however you wish.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i will request you to be a bit more specific if possible? Is it a case of going in to both of those files and simply changing the wording?

Comment: Its more than that. You have to go through the code, and find where exactly the price is being displayed. Make sure you are editing the right file in the active theme. Use template hints.